# Swift SceneDidLoad() .size

Tags: swift

Hi I'd like to get the size attribute of a scene from the sceneDidLoad() call

When I call sceneDidLoad. Like:

```
override func sceneDidLoad() {
    print(size)
    screenSize = setScreenSize(size)
}
```

I get an error message:

*Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'CGSize'*

If I omit the line

```
screenSize = setScreenSize(size)
```

Then the call to sceneDidLoad() prints the correct screen size.

Any ideas

Thanks

Comment: How about `screenSize = size`?

Comment: Ok made a mistake here thank you